# subset data frame based on character value

Tags: r, string, character, subset

I'm trying to subset a data frame that I imported with read.table using the `colClasses='character'` option.

A small sample of the data can be [found here](https://slapadabias.wordpress.com/?p=2&preview=true&preview_id=2)

```
Full99<-read.csv("File.csv",header=TRUE,colClasses='character')
```

After removing duplicates, missing values, and all unnecessary columns I get a data frame of these dimmensions:

```
>dim(NoMissNoDup99)
[1] 81551     6
```

I'm interested in reducing the data to only include observations of a specific `Service.Type`

I've tried with the subset function:

```
MU99<-subset(NoMissNoDup99,Service.Type=='Apartment'|
 Service.Type=='Duplex'|
 Service.Type=='Triplex'|
 Service.Type=='Fourplex',
 select=Service.Type:X.13)

 dim(MU99)
[1] 0 6

MU99<-NoMissNoDup99[which(NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type!='Hospital' 
                & NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type!= 'Hotel or Motel'
                & NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type!= 'Industry'
                & NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type!= 'Micellaneous'
                & NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type!= 'Parks & Municipals'
                & NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type!= 'Restaurant'
                & NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type!= 'School or Church or Charity'
                & NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type!='Single Residence'),]
```

but that doesn't remove observations.

I've tried that same method but slightly tweaked...

```
MU99<-NoMissNoDup99[which(NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type=='Apartment'
                |NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type=='Duplex'
                |NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type=='Triplex'
                |NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type=='Fourplex'), ]
```

but that removes every observation...

The final subset should have somewhere around 8000 observations

I'm pretty new to R and Stack Overflow, so I apologize if there's some convention of posting I've neglected to follow, but if anyone has a magic bullet to get this data to cooperate, I'd love your insights :)

Comment: Your link to a sample of data is broken.

Comment: Check the spelling of column names. If they have leading or trailing space it's going to be an (unpleasant) surprise. The `subset` looks like it should have succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different methods should work if you were using the right variable values. Your issue likely is extra spaces in your variable names.

You can avoid this kind of issues using `grep` for example:

```
NoMissNoDup99[grep("Apartment|Duplex|Business",NoMissNoDup99$Service.Type),]
```

Comment: the grep function solved the issue. I couldn't tell you what the issue was with the other methods I was trying, but this was a great fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ## exclude 
    MU99<-subset(NoMissNoDup99,!(Service.Type %in% c('Hospital','Hotel or Motel')))

    ##include
    MU99<-subset(NoMissNoDup99,Service.Type %in% c('Apartment','Duplex'))
```